# ComboBox Selected Item not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

## Problem

I am trying to bind a ComboBox's `SelectedItem` to a custom class but this does not update when the property is changed.`INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented.

## The DataContext

The `DataContext` is a custom class which contains many properties, but an extract of this is below. You can see it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and this called when the two properties are changed.

```
public class BctsChange : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region declarations
    private byContact _Engineer;

    public byContact Engineer
    {
        get { return _Engineer; }
        set
        {
            _Engineer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Engineer");
            OnEngineerChanged();
        }
    }

    private BctsSvc.DOSets _LeadingSet;

    public BctsSvc.DOSets LeadingSet
    {
        get { return _LeadingSet; }
        set { _LeadingSet = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("LeadingSet"); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotify
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public BctsChange()
    {
        Engineer = new byContact(Environment.UserName);
    }

    private void OnEngineerChanged()
    {
        if (Engineer != null)
        {
            BctsSvc.DOSets leadSet = GetLeadingSetFromDeptCode(Engineer.DeptCode);

            if (leadSet == null) return;
            LeadingSet = leadSet;
        }
    }


    private static BctsSvc.DOSets GetLeadingSetFromDeptCode(string DeptCode)
    {
        BctsSvc.BctsServiceSoapClient svc = new BctsSvc.BctsServiceSoapClient();
        BctsSvc.DOSets setX = svc.GetSetFromDeptCode(DeptCode);
        return setX;
    }
}
```

## The Window XAML

I have several controls on the window, but to keep the code simple I believe the following extract will suffice.

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.wdSubmit"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            x:Name="ucReqForm"
        Title="wdSubmit" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">        
        <GroupBox Header="Engineer Details" Name="grpOwnerDetails" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Engineer.FullName,  FallbackValue='Please select an engineer by clicking →', Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,0" IsEnabled="True" FontStyle="Italic" />
                    <Button Content="{StaticResource icoSearch}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" Name="btnSelectEngineer" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="Search for an engineer responsible" Click="btnSelectEngineer_Click" />
                </Grid>

                <ComboBox Height="23" x:Name="ddSet2" Margin="5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding LeadingSets, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding LeadingSet, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetName}" ToolTip="{Binding HelpInfo}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
                <my:LabelledDropdown Height="23" x:Name="ddSet" Margin="5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding LeadingSets, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding LeadingSet, Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Label="e.g. BodyHardware">
                    <my:LabelledDropdown.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetName}" ToolTip="{Binding HelpInfo}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </my:LabelledDropdown.ItemTemplate>
                </my:LabelledDropdown>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The above extract contains:

- A `Label` that contains a contact's name, and a button to search for a contact, bound to the `FullName` of the `Engineer`
- A `ComboBox` that contains departments within the company, bound to an `ObservableCollection<DOSets>`, which contains a list of departments
- Two `ComboBox`es, one which is a custom one and the other which is temporary to ensure the bug is not within the control. These are Databound to `LeadingSet`

## Window Code Behind

In the code behind I set the DataContext to `CurrentChange`. When the user wants to select a different `Engineer` then this will update the selected department for the engineer in `CurrentChange`.

When the user changes the engineer, the data binding for the engineer is updated, but the selected department (Leading Set) isn't.

```
//Usings here

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class wdSubmit : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private BctsSvc.BctsServiceSoapClient svc;

        private BctsChange _CurrentChange;

        public BctsChange CurrentChange
        {
            get { return _CurrentChange; }
            set { _CurrentChange = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentChange"); }
        }


        private List<BctsSvc.DOSets> _LeadingSets;
        public List<BctsSvc.DOSets> LeadingSets
        {
            get
            {
                return _LeadingSets;
            }
        }


        public wdSubmit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            svc = new BctsSvc.BctsServiceSoapClient();
            _LeadingSets = svc.GetLeadSets().ToList();
            OnPropertyChanged("LeadingSets");

            this._CurrentChange = new BctsChange();

            this.DataContext = CurrentChange;

            CurrentChange.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(CurrentChange_PropertyChanged);
        }

        void CurrentChange_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentChange");
            OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
        }

        private void btnSelectEngineer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            byContact newContact = new frmSearchEngineer().ShowSearch();

            if (newContact != null)
            {
                CurrentChange.Engineer = newContact;
                PropertyChanged(CurrentChange, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LeadingSet"));
                PropertyChanged(CurrentChange.LeadingSet, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LeadingSet"));

            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(CurrentChange, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realised the problem may be due to the `LeadingSet`, returned when the engineer is changed, being a different instance to that in the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. But you can try this : `LeadingSet = LeadingSets.Where(x=> x.Property==leadSet.Property).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Try to add `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` to your combobox properties